# How to remain on the same position after edit or delete data from nested recycler view

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-room

I have a nested recycler view that contains parent and child adapters. I am using Room DB for showing data on the recycler view.
`When I, add or delete data from a parent or child list item or parent list item, it goes to the first position.`

[This is how I, collect data from the view model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o75Zo.png)

[This is how I, collect data from Room DB and emit for activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQTMb.png)

[These are some edit delete operations executing in the activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9R6c.png)

`I just want when I, execute any operation the position remains the same not scroll for the first position. There is also a solution called the smooth Scroll To Position method but I want a solution without using this function.`

Comment: Never paste images of code rather than the code itself, It helps people to reproduce the problem. Help people to let help you.

Comment: Ok, always remember for next time

Answer (score 0):

In your `collect` lambda, you are setting the `recyclerView's` adapter every time a new `flow` is collected, which is making your `recyclerView` go on the top.

You should move `binding!!.parentRecyclerView.adapter = adapter` to either `onCreate` if using inside an `activity` or `onViewCreated` if fragment.

You can also do a `null` check and set only if the `recycler views` adapter is null. This should be avoided as it is more idiomatic to set it when the view gets created.